# Parsing XFN data with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, xfn

I'm trying to filter the XFN relationships meta data found in web pages.
It is something like this:

```
<a href="site" rel="friend colleague" >Name</a>
```

in REL you can have various values, like "friend", "collegue" but even "me" and "met" 
because you can have multiple values, I did this:

```
xfn_me = $("a[rel*=me]").length;
```

But this doesn't work, because both "me" and "met" are matched! 
Is there a way to filter the values exactly, even when there are multiple values?

Thank you.

*Please note that I have no control on the page, in fact I'm working on a Chrome extension, and this code should runs on any web page.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `[attribute~=value]` selector. It selects based on space-separated values exactly like how xfn and CSS classes work, i.e. `[class~=className]` is exactly the same as `.className`.

```
xfn_me = $("a[rel~=me]").length;
```

I couldn't find it in the jQuery documentation, but it works in 1.3 at least.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot, it really works despite it's missing from the jQuery documentation.

Comment: Woah! Very cool. I didn't know jQuery could do that. Here's hoping it makes it into the docs for 1.4

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you could do it this way:

```
$('a[rel*=me]').filter(function(){ 
   return $.inArray('me', $(this).attr('rel').split(' ')) > -1;
}).length;
```

That basically finds all the `a` elements that *might* be a match, then filters them by splitting the rel tag into an array and checking the actual match is found.

**Edit:** I updated my code from `!$.inArray` to `$.inArray > -1` as found by @UVL.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code showed me the path to follow, but have found that only matches part of the values, because inarray returns the index of the item found, and negating (!) it returns incorrect values.
Going to post the correct code below.

Answer (score 0):

A solution (until jquery 1.2 at least) is this:

```
xfn_me = $('a[rel*=me]').filter(function(){ 
 return $.inArray('me', $(this).attr('rel').split(' ')) > -1;
}).length;
```

Puts in `xfn_me` the number of `A` tags with `rel` matching "me", even when multiple rel values are used.